# Unable to display images in HTML using Webpack

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, webpack

I'm new to Webpack and I'm trying to build a simple web server.

When I run `npm run build`, my `jpg` files are created in my `dist` directory, along with duplicates that can't be loaded. I have an `src` directory that looks like this:

[image]

When I run `npm run build`, my `dist` directory looks like this:

[image]

In VS Code, I can see that the first and third `jpg`s generated in the `dist` folder are loaded correctly and I can see the image when I click on them. These are the only `jpg` files I expect to be generated. However, the first and fourth `jpg`s seem to be duplicate generated files, and when I click on them, VS Code shows this:

[image]

In the generated `index.html` file in the `dist` directory, we can see the HTML is using the `jpg` files that can't be loaded. We can see this shown here:

```
<img src="9941501b9ff26a2ac9eb.jpg">
```

Unsurprisingly, when I run my server with `npm run start:dev`, my page does not correctly display the image:

[image]

Here is the rule for loading images in my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader:'file-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

There has to be something I'm doing wrong here, but I'm not sure what it could be because I'm new to Webpack. Let me know if I can provide more information to help pinpoint the issue and I will be happy to do so.

Comment: Why not use [asset-management/#loading-images](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images)

Comment: @slideshowp2 This did the trick. Thanks a ton.